# Change ngx-bootstrap DatePicker locale from a centralized service

Tags: angular, localization, bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I am using the ngx-bootstrap DatePicker in an Angular presentation component:

```
<div class="datepicker-cal-wrap">
  <bs-datepicker-inline
    [bsValue]="selectedDate"
    (bsValueChange)="onValueChange($event)"
    [bsConfig]="{
      rangeInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      showWeekNumbers: false
    }"
  >
  </bs-datepicker-inline>
</div>`

export class DatePickerComponent {
  @Input()
  selectedDate = new Date();

  @Output()
  dateSelected: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter();

  // If I uncomment the code below, the local changes, but I would like to avoid this code here
  // constructor(private _localeService: BsLocaleService) {
  //   this._localeService.use('it');
  // }

  onValueChange(selectedDate: Date): void {
    this.dateSelected.emit(selectedDate);
  }
}
```

I have a centralized Translate Service that manages the current language code and translations, also for the generic Angular Translate pipe. Therefore, I would like to set the locale here, instead in each single component using the DatePicker:

```
import { BsLocaleService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { defineLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
import { itLocale, deLocale, enGbLocale, frLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';

registerLocaleData(localeFr);
registerLocaleData(localeDe);
registerLocaleData(localeIt);
registerLocaleData(localeEn);

// ngx-bootstrap
defineLocale('it', itLocale);
defineLocale('de', deLocale);
defineLocale('en', enGbLocale);
defineLocale('fr', frLocale);

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomTranslationService extends TranslateService {

  setLanguage(language: Languages) {
    this.use(language);

    //Even if I set the new locale, eg. 'it' the DatePicker does not change
    this.localeBsService.use(language);   // <--
  }

// ....
```

How could I set and change the DatePicker locale dynamically outside each component using the DatePicker?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can register the locales in the AppModule.

Take a look at this question and use it as a reference.

[Angular 6 ngx-bootstrap Datepicker global locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277347/angular-6-ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-global-locale)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).